# createjs load local files loadqueue

Tags: javascript, createjs

Im have been working on a project with the createjs library and I have used Brackets with Live preview where everything works perfectly, but if I just open the file in a browser I get the following error message in chrome.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Maskinen/Docuemnts/fail.fail. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

I have read that if I set loadqueue(false) I wouldnt get problems with loading local files. I therefore thought that when it was working in live preview in brackets everything was fine. Is it possible to run chrome or firefox as Brackets in live preview or similar? The project is part of an assignment and it isnt possible to use a webserver :(

Answer (score 0):

This it what is found by searching around for a bit:

If you launch chrome.exe like this it should work

chrome.exe --args --disable-web-security

When you're done restart chrome without the args and it works like normal again.

Source: 
http://robandlauren.com/2013/09/25/cross-origin-ajax-requests-localhost-chrome/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to be more specific to it and use `allow-file-access-from-files` flag.

To do that execute chrome with this option:

- Windows
  `cmd
  chrome --allow-file-access-from-files`
- Mac
  `bash
  open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --allow-file-access-from-files`

> Even thought this is disabling security protections so be careful with it, and enable it back to browse securely